# Oracle Dump Compatibility against Operating System

Tags: windows, oracle, operating-system, solaris, database-administration

We are using Oracle 11GR1 installed in windows Box. We exported a schema using Normal Exp/ EXPDP utilities.

Let us know if this can be imported in Sun Solaris/ Unix Based Operating system.

If yes,  please let us  know what could be the typical issues we see?

Comment: this can be imported without a glitch I believe, I do not see any issues

Answer (score 2):

Export files are designed to go across platforms so that should not create any problems.  You'd run into exactly the same issues that you would importing any other export file-- making sure that you're using the correct version of the export and import utilities, specifying how to handle cases where objects already exist, dealing with data issues if the export was not done in a consistent mode, etc.